# Binary tree doesn't go over to the right side in a recursion

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion, binary-tree

I was trying to make a function that checks whether or not the given tree is a [Factorization tree](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/factor-tree.html) of the number given in the function, but for some reason the function doesn't go on the right side of the tree and returns me the null pointer exception, in addition, it says the return true that iv'e made is a dead code and is never used and I don't understand why.I wanted that if there aren't any problems with the tree being a Factorization tree and i'm at the end of my tree that will return true.
The function :

```
 //input : The function gets a binary tree of integers and a number
//output : The function returns true if the tree is a Factorization tree and false otherwise
public static boolean isFactTree(BinTreeNode<Integer> t,int num){
    System.out.println(t.getValue());
    if(t==null)
        return true;
    else{
        if(!t.isLeaf()){
            if(((t.getLeft()==null)&&(t.getRight()!=null))||((t.getLeft()!=null)&&(t.getRight()==null))){
                return false;
            }
            if(t.getValue()!=((t.getLeft().getValue())*(t.getRight().getValue()))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if((!(isPrime(t.getValue())))&&(t.isLeaf()))
                return false;
        }
        return isFactTree(t.getLeft(),num) && isFactTree(t.getRight(),num);

    }
}
```

The tree is :

```
 public static BinTreeNode<Integer> buildtree(){
    BinTreeNode<Integer> t1=new BinTreeNode<Integer>(new 
    BinTreeNode<Integer>(10),20,new BinTreeNode<Integer>(2));
    //setting up the left side
    t1.getLeft().setLeft(new BinTreeNode<Integer>(2));
    t1.getLeft().setRight(new BinTreeNode<Integer>(5));
    //setting up the right side
    return t1;
}
```

I called the function liked that :

```
 System.out.println(isFactTree(t,20));
```

So the function should return true to the given tree.
I'll be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I don't actually think there was any problem here in the first place I think it was just a bug because I copied it again to a function using a different name and it worked